# Upload images to a Node.JS server without using <form>

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-uploading

I have a node.js server, which uses express-fileupload to accept images. Now I'm working on the function to upload an image. But I don't want to use < form > since I prefer xhtml request for various reasons, but mainly because I don't want to redirect the user, after he uploads an image.

I have tried reading the picture as dataURI, sending it to the server, decoding it and writing it to a file, which didnt work and seemed to resource intensive and laborious.

```
//I used the dataString from the callback method and wrote it to a file using fs.writeFile
function dataURItoimage(dataString, callback){
   const atob = require("atob");

   dataString.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
   dataString.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");

   atob(dataString);
   callback(null, dataString);
}
```

```
//User side code
avatarInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(avatarInput.files[0]);
    reader.onload = () => {
        avatar = reader.result;
        tosend.avatar = reader.result;
    }
}, false);

uploadButton.onclick = () => {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/avatarUpload");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var tosend = {avatar: ""};
    tosend.avatar = avatar;

    request.send(JSON.stringify(tosend));
}
```

Is there a better way to upload an image, which the user can select, to a node.js server?

Comment: You can make a regular multipart file upload request via AJAX, yes. You should be able to find examples if you search. It's normally done by making use of the FormData class

Answer (score 1):

So I did it this way:

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/test");

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", avatarInput.files[0]);
    request.send(fd);
```

I created a FormData Object, appended the image, which the user chose in an input called "avatarInput", and send the object to the server.
On server side I used  express-fileupload to access the file:

```
app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    if(req.files){
        //With the follwing command you can save the recieved image
        req.files.file.mv("./file.png",  (err) => {if(err)throw err});
    }
    res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example. It worked for me. I hope it can help you.

Sending dataURL throw Ajax request:

```
const dataURL = snapshotCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload-image',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { data: dataURL },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

Receiving request:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const base64 = req.body.data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    fs.writeFileSync(`uploads/images/newImage.jpg`, base64, {encoding: 'base64'});
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! This seems to work aswell, but i prefer plain Javascript (withou jQuery or similar). You can find my answer above.

Comment: Oh, sure. I'll try thinking another way.